# stacking transforms in D3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have an SVG element with a transform already applied to it (this could be a single translate, or a combination of multiple transforms). I'm trying to apply additional transform to it. Problem is that this transform could be applied repeatedly and needs to stack with the existing transform state (so appending additional transforms to the end is not practical). Looking through d3 API, I didn't notice anything that lets me apply a relative transform (although I must admit, I'm not that familiar with advanced features of d3). Manually parsing the current transform string and then computing the same transformation matrix that SVG already does behind the scenes for free seems silly, is there a better way?

For example, if existing element already has the following attribute:

```
transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)"
```

And I invoke this transformation logic twice, wanting to offset the element by 1 pixel in each dimension each time, I would need to parse and process both, the translate and rotate calls, because the new translations cannot be applied prior to rotation.

Comment: Okay, I answered quickly without reading carefully.  Can you explain why concatenating multiple transformation strings doesn't achieve your objective?  Maybe with pictures showing what you're trying to accomplish?  SVG transforms are by default relative and cumulative.

Comment: Imagine I call the logic that performs translate(1,1) 100 times (as in, let's say it gets invoked on every mousemove event), I will end up with `transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50) translate(1,1) translate(1,1) translate(1,1) ... translate(1,1) translate(1,1)"`. Now image if I call it 1000 times, now imagine I'm manipulating several elements at once. This is a lot of unnecessary memory and computational overhead for the DOM.

Comment: So what you want is to be able to go from `transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50) translate(1,1)"` to `transform="translate(30) rotate(45 50 50) translate(100,100)"`, replacing the last part of the transform based on some data variable without affecting the first part?

Comment: Because if so, it might be easiest just to wrap your element in a `<g>` element, set the "constant" transform on the `<g>`, and then you can just over-write the transform on your moving object without worrying about the constant part.  Otherwise, you're going to have to do some string parsing.

Comment: Well, that would work if transform would be the only operation. I also have rotation and scaling methods which could get called between those translates, so I would actually need to factor those in as well. I guess I can just use the matrix() and compute it manually. Parsing the matrix alone would be simpler than parsing everything. I was just hoping an out-of-the-box solution existed already.

Comment: I did some fiddling around.  In Firefox, you can get the current transformation matrix by setting transforms as styles instead of attributes, and then use `getComputedStyle(this)["transform"]`.  However, you have to use CSS transformations (with units) instead of SVG transformations (bare numbers).  And since Chrome doesn't fully support CSS transformations, that means you have to use "-webkit-transform" to apply the style.  And even though the style gets applied I get "none" back from `getComputedStyle(this)["-webkit-transform"]` or `getComputedStyle(this)["webkitTransform"]`.

Comment: Repurposing another poster's fiddle, [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/8dKJa/2/) logs to the console various CSS transform strings followed by the results of `getComputedStyle` on the transformed group.  At least, it does in Firefox.  Webkit browsers, not so much.  So I leave it here as a curiosity, not a practical solution.

Comment: Have you seen [`d3.transform`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Math#wiki-transform)? This should do exactly what you want.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Great tip.  Also, I discovered there are a number of Javascript functions to access current transformations and the computed matrix:  `Element.transform.baseVal.consolidate().matrix` will get you the current matrix on this element; `Element.getTransformToElement()` will get you a matrix representing all transforms, including transformations on parent elements.  But using d3 ready-made functions is probably easier.

Comment: Thanks, d3.transform does indeed work. Odd that it doesn't have methods for direct manipulation of the transform, but concatenating current transform with wanted and then running the string through d3.transform() produces desired result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Lars pointed out in a comment, d3.transform will generate the transform from the string. Applying that to my original problem, I can do the following:

```
element.attr('transform', d3.transform('translate(30) rotate(45 50 50) translate(1,1) translate(1,1)').toString())
```

Comment: for d3 version 4 I get `d3. transform() is not a function`

Answer (score 5):

I've actually been thinking that there should be a special function for this, similar to the way the `classed()` function handles adding and remove certain classes without messing up the other ones.

However, until that happens, just access the existing attribute and then concatenate strings:

```
selection.attr("transform", function(d){
        return this.getAttribute("transform") +
                     " translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)";
    });
```

You could also use `d3.select(this).attr("transform")` but the raw javascript should work and saves a function call.

Just be careful not to mix up attribute transforms with style transforms.

Comment: For d3v4 you don't need this.getAttribute() anymore, just return the "translate(30) rotate(45 50 50)" string.